# Laravel controllers not working in another computer

Tags: php, laravel

I just copied my laravel project from one pc into another. I changed the `.env` file accordingly for new domain url (it's in localhost bytheway).

However when I click the links, namely login, register, they say the requested URL not found on this server.

I tried to run `php artisan serve` command, but it says

> [Error Exception] No such file for directory.

But the artisan file is there. I'm afraid the domain still pointing to previous one, hence the error.

Is there anywhere else I need to change the pointing url?

Comment: What is the webserver? Nginx? Apache?

Comment: apache, wamp server currently. The project imported from xamp

Comment: How are your routes defined? How are the links being generated in your view? And how's your server configuration?

Comment: `php artisan confg:clear` then
`php artisan route:clear`

Comment: *If* you want to use `php artisan serve` make sure to run it from your project folder, that's where `artisan` is located. But since you're using Apache there's no need for that. Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled, basically that your vhost is set up correct.

Comment: Check your `.htaccess` file for your base path. You might be serving from different base directories. Or maybe `mod_rewrite` isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

After copying the directory you should always run `composer update` secondly make sure you have.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by enabling module rewrite option in apache extension in WAMP